# Painting bone weights that 'inherit'?

Tags: rigging, armature, interface, bones

It seems like I would have an easier time painting bone weights if it worked such that (for instance) a thigh bone would have weight set to 1 all the way down the entire leg, rather than becoming 0 again at the point that the knee bone takes over.  I understand why the data takes this form on a practical level in terms of how it's used for animation, but in terms of *editing* the bone weights it means that I'm manually managing all of the boundaries between bones and their children *twice* -- once on the parent, and then again on the child.

In fact, in practice I often wind up awkwardly manually doing it the way I'm hoping for, by painting the whole leg for the thigh, and then subtracting the knee weights from it using the "Vertex Weight Mix" modifier, which works fine, but is the kind of repetitive manual work that it seems like a computer could be doing for me automatically in a compilation step...

I could've sworn that at one point I saw documentation for a mode in Blender that works the way I'm hoping, but since then I've totally failed to track it down again.  Does this mode exist at all?  Or are there at least any user scripts that will iterate down a bone hierarchy and perform all those "vertex weight mix" subtractions automatically once I'm ready to export the result?  Or am I looking at this all wrong and there's something that makes this approach to authoring bone weights make sense?

Comment: When I paint manually, I'll paint from root outwards, and I'll do a gradient, then a normalize all operation (on default "lock active" setting), then another gradient, then another normalize all, etc.  This is basically what you want.  For regular painting, you can use autonormalize instead (doesn't work with gradients.)  Blender doesn't know what should override what though: if you paint foot then leg, Blender needs to know which one is subordinate to the other.  That's why order of painting is important.

Comment: I could see that being a good approach for working from scratch, but I'm thinking more of circumstances where I'm tweaking the boundary between two bones long after my first pass at bone weights is already finished, and I wind up having to do that tweak on both the parent and child bone...